# Is it safe to travel to Miami Beach shortly after hurricane Irma?

Tags: safety, weather-and-climate, event-based-effects, miami

Two months ago my girl and I booked our vacation. We are from Berlin, Germany and wanted to see the U.S.
Our first stop is Miami Beach at the 15th and we want to stay there for 3 days and continue to NYC. Later on we will go to Vegas and come back to Miami the 26th of September and stay there another 4 nights.

I expect the hurricane will be gone by the 15th, but I have no idea whether it will be okay. For me okay means that we can reach our hotel and sleep there.

What do you suggest? I know this question is primarily opinion based, but here in Germany we don't have hurricanes and I don't know how fast the state will recover.

Comment: Don't forget that Hurricane Jose is still off the south-east and at this stage they are unsure quite where that's going to go.  It's currently Category 3.  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/capital-weather-gang/wp/2017/09/10/hurricane-jose-to-meander-not-far-from-u-s-east-coast-for-days-in-threatening-position/

Comment: @Midavalo Jose is expected to stay in the Atlantic for at [least the next 6 days](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/graphics_at2.shtml?cone). It's not expected to get anywhere near as strong as Irma during that time period either.

Comment: If you visit undamaged areas it is probably okay.  But even weeks after an event of this size, emergency services will still be in the area and clean-up is considered part of this process.  The less the number of unnecessary people running around in damaged areas the better from a disaster relief perspective.  Don't be surprised if police/fire/NGOs ask you to turn around and leave if you have no purpose being there, even if the purpose is tourism.

Comment: Or they'll hand you a broom... but watch out whether volunteer labor is permitted on your visa.

Comment: Read the Herald.  http://www.miamiherald.com

Comment: I realize you've spent money on this and everything, but recovery from this hurricane is going to go on for months. My understanding, based on news reports, is that large parts of the state of Florida are without electrical power. The people who live there are dealing with a major disaster, and the recovery will take months, at least. This is not a place you should be going for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I would try to call the hotel.  If they are not even able to answer the phone then they certainly are in no state to service guests.  If they can answer the phone then they will have answers for you.  Also call your airline - they can tell you about the status of your flights.  Random people on the internet cannot possibly give you better information than you will get there.

Comment: Also keep in mind that people who actually live in Florida and have evacuated are still having a very hard time just getting back home - roads are damaged, there is no fuel for transportation, emergency services are stretched to the limit - the state is a disaster area right now.  Unless there's something extremely important you need to be there for you're best to probably keep clear and start your travel somewhere else.  Even trying to travel across the state is going to be difficult for the next few days or more.

Comment: South Florida is **not a wasteland**.  I live there.  Should you travel the South Beach on September 15?  Depends on what your hotel says, but, even if it is operational, you will likely have a better experience somewhere else.  Walt Disney World and Universal Studios are nearly 100% operational already.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Will it be safe? Yes. The hurricane will be long gone so there will be no danger. Will it be recovered by then? No, it won't. Not fully. the destruction caused will take months and years to rebuild. It took new Orleans a full year after Katrina before they started promoting tourism again. Miami is both a county and a city so the amount of destruction depends on which you're referring to. You can visit key Biscayne and some of the beaches which don't have as many structures but most of Miami will likely still be a mess. However, the airlines and hotels will surely be glad to take your money, just don't expect to see the same Miami you see in pictures and on the internet.

Comment: There's a possibility flights may be canceled/redirected if the airports are significantly damaged, though, is there not?

Comment: @JAB Its already passed thru Miami dade and weakened significantly. I haven't heard any news about any airports being damaged, but if they had been they usually close the affected terminals, not the entire airport. Every cancelled flight is tens of thousands of dollars down the drain for the airlines.

Comment: And note that there's no guarantee the hotel will be operational when you get there.

Comment: Actually, a recent study/article suggests that [the last hurricane to make landfall in Florida killed more people after the storm than during](http://www.latimes.com/nation/fl-hurricane-survival-tips-story.html). Most of those killed were apparently locals doing local-type things, not tourists doing touristy things, but it's not clear that Miami will be back to pre-Irma safely levels by the 15th.

Comment: @1006a that's just math. The storm occurs during a finite period of time. "After the storm" is an infinite period of time. But good to note! Thank you

Comment: thank you all for the support. I will book a flight to vegas today. Will cost me 1200 euros and I won't get a refund for the miami flight.

Comment: @RayofCommand Make sure you see Berwyn's answer below. As I read the BA waiver, you'd still have to pay the difference in fare, but if you contact them, you should be able to apply the value of the Miami flight to a flight to Vegas and save some money.

Comment: thanks i know about that. BA offers me to buy a trip to vegas for 1,9 K back and forth. While others offer it for 1,1k for me and my girl. So id rather do it this way.... I paid only 780 for us both flights so its in general more

Comment: I visited Cancun six months after a major hurricane, and half of the (mid-priced) hotel was still little more than rubble. This did explain the discount, although we stayed in the intact portion.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - imagine how much more you could have saved if you'd stayed in the other half. :-)

Comment: I am downvoting because as a Miami resident, this Answer is not reflective of the reality of life in South Florida.  By the end of the month, there won't be much a tourist would recognize as storm damage.  Miami and the Beaches will be 99.95% ready for the winter season.  That's just how we roll.  We got hit by Katrina and Wilma back to back.

Comment: @Johns-305 I live in tampa and travel to Miami once a month or so. OP is not gonna be there at the end of the month, he'll be there in two days and tonnes of people still won't even have electricity by then. Mine just came back on yesterday and tampa wasn't hit nearly as hard as South florida.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I did recommend alternate arrangements in the main thread.  The NHC Wind History indicates Tampa Bay experienced higher sustained winds than Miami and the Beaches.  Power should be near fully restored by Sunday.

Answer (score 44):

Miami Airport [experienced "significant water damage"](https://twitter.com/emiliotgonzalez/status/907022111688065026) in the storm. It will be [closed](https://twitter.com/iflymia/status/907070138180141056) on Monday the 11th, and they'll determine tomorrow whether they're able to resume flights on the 12th or whether further repairs are necessary. Each airline will decide when to operate once the airport reopens.

Miami Beach was evacuated and [will not allow people back in until Tuesday the 12th at noon](http://www.miamiherald.com/news/weather/hurricane/article172517041.html) (and then, only residents with ID) and some areas are [flooded](https://www.washingtonpost.com/video/local/weather/sept-10-storm-surge-floods-streets-in-miami-beach/2017/09/10/e67ac5f6-9662-11e7-af6a-6555caaeb8dc_video.html) today. 75% of Miami-Dade County [has no electricity](http://www.miamiherald.com/news/weather/hurricane/article172467631.html) right now, and the county is under a curfew. It is likely that your hotel doesn't know whether they can operate or whether they have power and won't know until after the roads reopen and staff can reach the hotel.

There's likely to be a lot more clarity by Wednesday, after they've started to clear the roads, people have had a chance to get back into Miami Beach, electrical crews have begun repairs, and the extent of the damage is surveyed. The city does "foresee" being open to visitors [by Thursday](https://twitter.com/MiamiBeachNews/status/907053651419697152), but you'll want to keep an eye on their communications and the Miami Herald newspaper for updates. That said, to me, Friday seems quite early to visit Miami Beach.

Personally, I'd change my trip to start someplace else in the US besides Florida on the 15th, keep an eye on the news, and go enjoy Miami starting on the 26th, assuming that things are sufficiently open then to have a good time.

Comment: good information, but in the context of some of the other comments your first paragraph might be a little misleading. all major florida airports closed before the storm simply because it's not safe to fly in that weather, not because of any damage. you only need a runway to resume flights. they didn't always have terminals. runways do not sustain water damage. mia is [resuming operations monday](https://twitter.com/sallyshin/status/907037325124829184) (today).

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. MIA is [quite adamant](https://twitter.com/iflymia/status/907070138180141056) that they will not be operating commercial passenger flights on Monday, though some airlines will fly empty planes and crews in. They would like to reopen on Tuesday, but aren't committing to that right now. That's the most recent information they've made available, as of a couple hours ago. I don't see how reporting what the airport authority is saying is misleading.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce ["There are no passenger flights scheduled at MIA September 11...After damage assessment, we will determine if passenger flights will resume on Tuesday, September 12."](https://twitter.com/iflymia/status/907070138180141056) and ["@iflymia will be closed on Monday September 11."](https://twitter.com/emiliotgonzalez/status/907044361367687168) I will fully acknowledge ATC may be open, but if the airport is not open to passengers, that is all that matters to actual travelers, and this isn't a site for airline ops departments. Anyway, the OP doesn't travel until the 15th.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Right. Well, when he updates us to tell us he isn’t using an airplane, we’ll update this answer. This site is bonkers sometimes...

Comment: I have a ticket for british airways from London to Miami Airpot ;) but I have to say that I would love to try the slingshot

Answer (score 20):

This is not quite an answer to your question, but I think it might be useful due to your recent comment that you're booked on BA (instead of a submarine) and you did ask for suggestions:

https://www.britishairways.com/travel/flightops/public/en_gb

> We are also providing rebook options for customers booked to fly with
>   us to/from Miami, Fort Lauderdale, Tampa, or Orlando between now and
>   17 September inclusive. They can choose to fly to the same destination
>   as originally booked up to and including 14 October. **Customers can
>   also use the value of their ticket towards an alternative destination
>   on our network if they no longer wish to travel to/from Florida**.

If you have not yet rebooked, call BA and ask for the cost of your existing flight to be applied towards your new one. If you have already rebooked without availing yourself of this, you have a 24 free cancellation period in order which could allow you to cancel and then rebook.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Irma will be gone, but the destructions caused by it will be visible for sure at that time.

Change your flight, if able.

A friend changes his flight from Athens to Miami, with only 100 euros extra charge, because he was afraid that he would be trapped to Constantinopole (transit airport for the flight). After two days the price for a date change went to 1200 euros.

Answer (score 1):

I do not live in Miami, however I planned a trip for next month. First I would call the hotel to ensure it will be open and available for use.
But it also depends on the area in which you are traveling to, as Florida Keys received one of the biggest hits. I am following hashtags of Miami and Miami beach area and business owners and residents have returned as of September 12 2017.
A lot of the pictures and videos show trees that have fallen, however it appears as if the damage is being repaired for this, nothing showed major flooding and business are returning back to normal. As long as your hotel is up in running I think you will be fine, as the beach looks beautiful on the pictures.

Don't let the comments about Jose scare you, as the tropical storm is headed north east and is not headed in the direction of Miami.