# Canceled my flight to Miami and go to a different location in the U.S. does my ESTA work?

Tags: usa, esta, tips-and-tricks

I recently asked about the safety of my travel to Miami. [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101872/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-miami-beach-15th-of-september-to-19th-after-hurricane-ir)
Now I had to cancel my hotel in Miami and I will not take my flight to Miami. Instead I go to Vegas or NY. 
On my ESTA appliance I had to name an address where I will stay in the U.S.
I gave the address of the hotel I booked.
Now I am concerned that I have to apply a new ESTA or change my old one, does anyone know how this works out? I don't want to end up being returned at the U.S. Airport.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand why this is a duplicate at all? How does the linked question explain whether or not the address can be updated (or needs to be updated) or whether one must reapply if the address changes?

Comment: @Moo then, I think we need to re-tag the duplicate

Comment: @Danh which one?

Comment: @Moo the one you mentioned

Comment: I meant tag this question as the duplicate of the one you mentioned

Comment: That question isn't exactly a duplicate either, since it's about a second trip and this is about the first trip, just with the destination changed. That said, the answer is correct: no you don't need to reapply. But if it makes you feel better, you can always go to the [ESTA site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), go to the check status section, and change the address without reapplying or paying a new fee.

Comment: @ZachLipton read this part: "Travelers may update this information when their plans are finalized, but they will not be required to update their destination addresses or itineraries should they change after their ESTA application has been approved. DHS recommends that ESTA applications be submitted as early as possible, as soon as, or even before travel is planned."  They dont really care if the itinerary changes, whether its first use or second use.

Comment: @ZachLipton ok, lets reopen it and answer it with a very similar answer :D