# Does it make sense to have a trip to Florida?

Tags: planning, weather-and-climate, event-based-effects, florida, miami

I have planned a trip to Florida (Orlando-Cape Canaveral-West Palm Beach-national Park-Miami) it includes Miami 0.01-10.05. How do you think, does it make sense to spend there 5 days and overall 2 weeks on Florida? I'm from Poland, there's no hurricanes there so I do not know what to expect. Will it be fine till then or should we change our plans? How is the situation right now there? I would be so thankful for any advises!

Comment: "includes Miami 0.01-10.05" ??? what dates are those ?

Comment: [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101872/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-miami-beach-15th-of-september-to-19th-after-hurricane-ir) is quite similar to what you are asking.