# Is it safer to travel to Miami after Irma at the end of September?

Tags: miami

A friend and I booked a hotel in Miami before Irma hit town. Our plans are to stay in Miami from October 1 to 6. Will the situation have recovered by then and will it be safe to stay there? We wrote an e-mail to the hotel but until now there is no answer. The hotel is located in Little Havana in Miami.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to travel to Miami Beach shortly after hurricane Irma?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101872/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-miami-beach-shortly-after-hurricane-irma)

Comment: Did you call them on the Phone?

Comment: Only the hotel will know if that particular hotel will be fully functioning. Keep asking them. If they don't answer you can probably assume they are not functioning.

Answer (score 4):

It will be safe in October, because it's already safe now. Life is back to normal.
If the hotel is still standing, everything is fine. If it is blown away, it won't be back in October (or anytime soon). Only the hotel will know.